# Antivirus/firewall software collision?

Tags: anti-virus

I use McAffee as my antivirus usually, but I recently encountered a trojan that Mcaffee couldn't fix. So, I installed Malwarebytes' Anti-Malware at the suggestion of a friend.

Malwarebytes fixed that trojan for good.

The next day, I turn on my laptop and Mcaffee alerts me that my comp is not fully protected. I hit "fix", and it fixed itself.

I think there was some change made when I installed malwarebytes that made THAT my primary antivirus instead of the more useful Mcaffee.

What was changed, and how can I make Mcaffee my primary antivirus again, or at least set it to fix itself whenever there is an issue?

Thanks for the help, this is a pretty big issue...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trial version of Malwarebytes has limited functionality. It does often catch things other antivirus misses. You'd want to uninstall mcaffee - there may be tools to help if your install is too far gone, available from mcafee, to remove it, then reinstall.